# Best method for preventing flooding of comments

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, security

I have a commenting system that I build which is similar to typical social media like Facebook. The user can post a comment beneath a thread. As it stands, someone could type something and hit enter extremely fast and over and over again and basically "spam" the system.

What would be the best method to prevent this type of flooding with javascript/jQuery?

There's a hidden input/submit button that's triggered when they hit enter, so I want to attach some type of event on that button:

1. Only allow a comment every 10 seconds.
2. Only allow X amount of comments during session and warn the user when this is breached.

   ```
   <input id="comment" placeholder="Post a comment" />
   <a id="post" class="btn">Post</a>
   ```

Comment: You need to protect against that on the server.

Comment: Using CSRF tokens in the submit form also significantly curtails the rate at which the attacker can send you valid form data.

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the best method to prevent this type of flooding with javascript/jQuery?

There is no good way to use client side code to do this. Don't ask the client to prevent itself from flooding. Implement rate limiting (based on username or ip address) on the server.